# rpm build directory creation during runtime

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

will the rpmbuild command create the topdir or rpmdir or any required rpm build directories if it does not exist.
Currently my spec file points the _topdir as pwd
if i want the topdir to be changed to pwd/test and if test does not exist will the rpmbuild command create it and proceed  ?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of creating missing directories varies with
versions of RPM, but in general, RPM attempts to create
missing directories.

Try-and-see whether your version of RPM creates missing
directories. If not, it's likely a very simple patch and back port.

Meanwhile doing
    %define _topdir ...
may be too late to handle sanely: rpm has already committed to
a %{_topdir} value before parsing a spec file.

Instead of attempting to redefine %_topdir in a *.spec file,
try defining on ~/.rpmmacros (or any other colon separated path mentioned
either by --macros=... or in the /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc (where ~/.rpmmacros
is specified by default) will ensure that
    %define _topdir ...
is specified sufficient;y early to meet your requirements.